# Unable to achieve full Jest coverage (Jest + Enzyme + React)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, storybook

the following is my function I have written in React:

```
    export const getColorClassName = ({ color, shade }: DnColorProps): string => {
return `is-${color}-${shade}`;
```

};

Jest coverage not met, report given as follows:
[image]

Please suggest how to write a Jest + Enzyme test for the above function!

Comment: Call it and check the result?

Comment: @DaveNewton I have called it and checked but I need to write a JEST + Enzyme test case to it 

something like this...
it('should render with default props', () => {
        expect.assertions(1);

        const rendered = render(<h3 className={`is-default`}>Helvetica - {DnFontWeight.default}</h3>);

        expect(rendered).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

Comment: It's not a component; why not just a straight JS test? Is there more code you're not showing? It's unclear what the specific issue is.